# How to Unmarshall/Marshall JSON in Go with Tags?

Tags: json, go

The JSON object:

```
{  
"foo_bar": "content"  
}
```

The code:

```
type PrettyStruct struct {
    Foo       string  `json: "foo_bar"`
}

func whatever(r *http.Request) {
    var req PrettyStruct

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req); err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    log.Println(req)
}
```

This outputs simply:

```
{}
```

Go isn't considering my tags when decoding the JSON object, so nothing is unmarshalled into the struct and every field stays with the zero-value.
If, in the JSON object, the field was called "foo" or "Foo", everything works normally.

I've tried the simple tag `"foo_bar"` and the following variations `` `json: foo_bar` `` and `"json: foo_bar"`.

Any thoughs on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's silly.. but the space between the colon and the `"foo_bar"` is the problem. Try this:

```
type PrettyStruct struct {
    Foo       string  `json:"foo_bar"`
    //                     ^^^ no space here
}
```

Working example on the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/dEc_c0UAOC

Comment: I think `go vet` may catch this (and some other common bugs!).

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot.  
But since the tag ```"foo_bar"``` doesn't have any spaces, why didn't that work? Does the json package only consider json tags? I thought that tags without labels were generic ones.

Comment: @ThiagoMartins struct tags can't have spaces between the key and the value, so it has to be `key:"value value2"`, in your case it's `json:"foo_bar"`, you can't have spaces around the `:`.

Comment: The format of a struct tag is described in: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag